# How to print different value for each table row using javascript

Tags: javascript

I just want to create a multiplication table using Javascript but I don't want each row to have the same result. I will picture that table I want to be created for my work

In this code, the program will print 9 times

```js
for (a = 1; a <= 9; a++) {
  document.write('<div style= "float: left; margin: 25px">')
  for (i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
    document.write(a + ' x ' + i + ' = ' + a * i + '</br>');
  }
}
```

I already make a table for multiplication but I don't want to make all print 10 times. I want to make different for each table cell

I want to make like this picture  and I'm new with JavaScript

[image]

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cPjot.png

Comment: Don't use document.write and don't hard code the value as 9.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var times = 1;
for (a = 9; a > 0; a--) {
  for (i = 9; i > 0 && i > (9 - times); i--) {
    document.write(a + ' x ' + i + ' = ' + a * i + ' ');
  }
  document.write('<br>');
  times++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add this to the second loop `for (i = 1; i <= a; i++)` that way you'll achieve what you want.

```js
for (a = 1; a <= 9; a++) {
  document.write('<div style= "float: left; margin: 5px">')
  for (i = 1; i <= a; i++) {
    document.write(a + ' x ' + i + ' = ' + a * i + '</br>');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is replace this line `for (i=1; i<=9; i++) {` with this: `for (i=a; i<=9; i++) {`

```js
for (a = 1; a <= 9; a++) {
  document.write('<div style= "float: left; margin: 25px">')
  for (i = a; i <= 9; i++) {
    document.write(a + ' x ' + i + ' = ' + a * i + '</br>');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For having the exact same thing as you posted in your picture, this code do the job :

```js
document.write("<table>");
for (a = 9; a > 0; a--) {
  document.write("<tr>")
  for (i = 9; i > a - 1; i--) {
    document.write('<td>' + a + ' x ' + i + ' = ' + a * i + '</td>');
  }
  document.write('</tr>')
}
document.write("</table>")
```

Note the use of decrementing loop to match the order of your picture and the usage of the table